# Reverse Boolean value in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony2 and the Doctrine query builder. Is there an easy way to reverse a Boolean in the database?

I've tried this with no luck:

```
    $query->update('AppMonitorBundle:Monitor', 'm')
            ->set('m.isActive', '!m.isActive')
            ->where('m.id = :monitor')
            ->setParameter('monitor', $monitor)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute()
    ;
```

Which I believe would work in SQL but it gives me:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 51: Error: Expected Literal, got '!'
```

Substituting ! for NOT gives the same result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a workaround:

```
->set('m.isActive', '1-m.isActive')
```

Tested and worked for me.

A boolean is just a 0 (as false) and 1 (as true). So if `m.isActive` is true, then the reverse value will `false (1-1 = 0 = false)`. And if `m.isActive` is false, the reverse side will `true (1-0 = 1 = true)`.