# How to query UPDATE SET field = !field in Doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder, doctrine-query

I want to make a query like "**UPDATE category c SET c.display = !c.display**"
but I get an exception.

**My code:**

```
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$q = $qb->update('Category', 'c')
        ->set('c.display', '!c.display')
        ->getQuery();

$p = $q->execute();
```

**I get an exception**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message 'UPDATE Category c SET c.display = !c.display' in /opt/web/sites/site/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:41
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/web/sites/site/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(448): Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::dqlError('UPDATE Category...')
#1 /opt/web/sites/site/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(2586): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->syntaxError('Literal')
#2 /opt/web/sites/site/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(2774): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->Literal()
#3 /opt/web/sites/site/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(2708): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ArithmeticPrimary()
#4 /opt/web/sites/site/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(2676): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ArithmeticFactor()
#5 /opt/web/sites/site/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(2650): Doctrine\ORM\Quer in /opt/web/sites/site/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php on line 52
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a database where a boolean is stored as 1 or 0, you could try this

```
$q = $qb->update('Category', 'c')
        ->set('c.display', '1 - c.display')
        ->getQuery();
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18458617/3574819 (SO didn't let me mark as duplicate because that answer was not accepted)